# How to show byte array of image in gallery as image in xamarin.ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am downloading an image from api. This api provides me the bytes of image. Now I want to show this image in gallery (like normal images that is available in gallery). Means when user click the button in app, it should download the image's byte array and the image should open in full screen in gallery.

Like this

[image]

Comment: just write the bytes to disk as an image file and then load it from there

Comment: I can write the bytes into image and save it in local disk, but then how can I directly load it from there. I think user need to tap the image in gallery only then he can load it. But I want that user should not click anything in gallery to load image. When user click on the item in my app, then image should download and load directly like this.

Comment: once you save the image, just update the Image controls source to point to the file on disk

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save this to system gallery. You can try to convert your byte array to `UIImage`, then save this image:

```
NSData data = NSData.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
// Or NSData data = NSData.FromArray(imageBytes);
UIImage img = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
img.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
{

});
```

On iOS 11, if you want to add images to photo library, do not forget to add the `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` key in info.plist:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Our application needs permission to write photos...</string>
```

Comment: I also need to open gallery and pick same image to show like the image I attached with my query

Comment: This can save images to gallery. If you want to pick it later, use UIImagePicker to achieve that.